# Creating calendar - Speeding up PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm working on a calendar for my office. Every people has his own column and there is a line for every day.

There are some periodic date, where, for example, given people have to be working on the week-end. But most of the dates are coming from a MySQL database.

So it does a double loop (people vs dates) in which every dates have to be check for the person, what kind of occupation he has on this day.

Is there a way to optimize this script, because online it take at least 2-3 seconds (only 0.03 seconds according to PHP, but I don't feel like it's correct) and more than 8 seconds (again according to PHP) on our network! And this is just for 5 months, we'd like to have it for the whole year.

You can find a test version here (just to see the HTML and CSS): http://mybees.ch/for/tableau_one_query_table.php

And here is the PHP in it (I grouped the second query in the first one and use table):

```php
// Initiating the dates
$year = 2020;
$date1 = "$year-01-01";
$date2 = "$year-12-31";

//Creating the line for the workers
$ids;
$activity = array();
$worker_query_text = "SELECT DISTINCT w.id, w.name, w.forename, w.group
                        FROM worker w, worker_position wp
                        WHERE w.id = wp.maid AND w.grup != 14
                        ORDER BY w.grup, wp.posid, w.name, w.vorname";
$worker_query = mysqli_query($bdi, $worker_query_text);
while($worker = mysqli_fetch_assoc($worker_query)) {
    echo '<div class="cell name">'.$worker['name'].' '.$worker['forename'].'</div>';
    $ids[] = $worker['id'];
    $group[$worker['id']] = $worker['group'];
    
    $activity_query_text = "SELECT date1, date2, activity_type.id as type, moment, remark, location FROM activity, activity_type WHERE activity_type.id = activity.type AND id_ma=".$worker['id']." AND date1 BETWEEN CAST('$date1' AS DATE) AND CAST('$date2' AS DATE)";
    $activity_query = mysqli_query($bdi, $activity_query_text);
    while($activity_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($activity_query)) {
        $activity[$worker['id']][] = $activity_row;
    }
}
```

```php
// Check if special group day
$firstGroup = 1;
$firstDate = strtotime("$year-01-01");
$picket = array();

if (date("N", $firstDate) ==  2)// Tuesday
    $firstDate -= 24 * 3600;
elseif (date("N", $firstDate) ==  3)// Wednesday
    $firstDate -= 2 * 24 * 3600;
elseif (date("N", $firstDate) ==  5)// Friday
    $firstDate -= 24 * 3600;
elseif (date("N", $firstDate) ==  6)// Saturday
    $firstDate -= 2 * 24 * 3600;
elseif (date("N", $firstDate) ==  7)// Sunday
    $firstDate -= 3 * 24 * 3600;

for ($date = $firstDate; $date <= strtotime("$year-12-31"); $date += 24 * 3600) {
    $weekNb = date("W",$date);
    $weekDay = date("N",$date); // Monday = 1, Sunday = 7
    if ($weekDay < 4)
        $group = $weekNb % 4 - 1 + $firstGroup;
    else
        $group = $weekNb % 4 - 2 + $firstGroup;
    
    if ($group == 0)
        $group = 4;
    if ($group == -1)
        $group = 3;
    
    $picket[$date] = $group;
}

$groupColor = ["yellow", "blue", "red", "green"];

function isPicket($date, $grup) {
    global $picket, $groupColor;
    if ($grup < 5) {
        if ($picket[$date] == $grup)
            return " style='background-color: ".$groupColor[$picket[$date]-1]."'";
    }
}
$today_stp = time() - time() % (24 * 3600) - 11 * 24 * 3600;
for ($date = strtotime($date1); $date <= strtotime($date2); $date += 24 * 3600) {
    $today = ($date == $today_stp) ?  ' id="today"':'';
    echo "<tr class='clear'$today>";
    $class = (date('N', $date) < 6) ? 'week' : 'weekend';

    echo "<td class='date $class line'>".date("D, d.m.", $date)."</td>";
    
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        echo "<td class='cell line $class'".isPicket($date,$grup[$id]).">
            <div class='small-cell".isColor($id, $date, 0)."' id='divUp-".$id."-$date'>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class='small-cell".isColor($id, $date, 1)."' id='divDown-".$id."-$date'>&nbsp;</div>
        </td>";
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

function isColor($id_ma, $date, $moment) {
    global $activity;

    if (array_key_exists($id_ma, $activity)) {
        foreach ($activity[$id_ma] as $activity_row) {
            if ($date >= strtotime($activity_row['date1']) && $date <= strtotime($activity_row['date2'])) {
                if ($activity_row['moment'] == $moment || $activity_row['moment'] == 2) {
                    $type = $activity_row['type'];
                    $style = "";
                    
                    if ($type > 1 && $type < 5)
                        $style = " urlaub";
                    if ($type > 4 && $type < 8)
                        $style = " frei";
                    if ($type > 7 && $type < 11)
                        $style = " ferien";
                    if (($type > 22 && $type < 34) || ($type > 37 && $type < 48))
                        $style = " kurse";
                    if ($type > 10 && $type < 17)
                        $style = " krank";

                    return " $style' title='".$activity_row['remark'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the modified code, I gain some precious time (one whole year takes now as much time as it was before for 3 monthes), but to create a table on one year, it still takes more than 10 seconds (13 seconds on my local server). Am I asking to much to PHP, should I limit the time span (only 2-3 monthes instead of one whole year)?

Comment: I think the first step here would be to have an understandable and consistent database. Don't mix German and English there, just use English. So the table name `ma`, which I think means "Mitarbeiter", should be something as understandable as `worker`, `employee` or anything similar. Same for the `ma_pos` table. Don't abbreviate unnecessarily. You have two tables called: `frei` and `free`. That's the same word in different languages. How should we even start to understand what they contain? Only when this has been resolved can you start to think about a next step.

Comment: Are you checking comments to your own question? Probably the best way to speed up your script is to perform one database query instead of many, but if we want to give you advice on this, we need a clear idea about how your database works. Please regard my previous comment in that context.

Comment: Hi KIKO, thanks for your remarks. Sorry, forgot the code is not as clear for everyone as it is for me. I made some changed in the published one, I hope it's now better and I didn't make any mistake. I'll look at your suggestion about doing only one DB query. But is it a correct way to store it in arrays like I've done?

Comment: You could include info how many queries are run for each page refresh? Maybe add detailed info about your query (run query with word `EXPLAIN` at the beginning) or/and DB structure (relevant part).

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot understand your code well enough to provide an useful answer. There are things missing, like the definition of `$time1` and `$time2`. Talking about these variables, you use those inside your query strings, and who knows where they are coming from? They might even be under the control of the user of your code. In that case inserting them into the query string is a big mistake (see: **SQL-injection**). The normal way to include PHP variables into a query string is by using: [Prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the comments. It takes me a bit of time to make the recommanded changes, but I'll get to you as soon as I've done it. Just about $date1 and 2 here are there declarations:`$year = 2020;$date1 = "$year-06-01 00:00 GMT";$date2 = "$year-06-30 00:00 GMT";` Then the user will just have a select to choose the year (once working, it should show the whole year).

Comment: I made some changes according to the comments, but I still have work to do next week: take every divs away; use prepared statements. As I understand, this last is exactly done for what I'm doing to do on the second query (using the workers ID as variable), am I right?

Comment: Oh dear, I now see that you **do** have a query in a loop. That will be slow. I either missed that before, or you have changed it. As for your question: `$worker['id']` comes from the database and could be considered "safe". Strictly speaking you wouldn't have to use a prepared statement for that, however, code changes over time, and it best to use basic safe practices. That means: Always use a prepared statement when you include PHP variables in your query. Another advantage is that if you prepare the query once, **before** the loop, it will execute slightly faster inside the loop.

Comment: I see possible issues with your data model but we would need more insight into the table definition (would be nice to see sample data too). Running the **explain** command should give you some clue about performance. What you want is to take advantage of indexes if any, you might need indexes on the workers and/or the dates but by using CAST over your dates you are effectively forcing a table scan that maybe could be avoided. Something like this should work fine in Mysql: `date1 BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'`. And indeed use prepared queries, watch out for SQL injections.

Comment: Hi @KIKO Software, yes, there is a loop in a loop, the first listed all the workers, the second all their activities (was already in the first script I gave, it was just not as readable as the last one as I inserted the second query by reading the table created by the first query, I also saved a lot of running time by doing so). I tried to separate the queries, it works, but it's worse. I'm using now the prepared statement (outside the loop), there is a win but not something extraordinary.

Comment: Hi @Volvox and Anonymous, you can find the result of both queries explained there: [queries.xlsx](http://mybees.ch/for/queries.xlsx). I don't understand how I'll help, but I hope it will.

Comment: That output is simply too big.  Think how unwieldy it will be if you triple the number of employees!  Let's go back to the drawing board.  What will the information be used for?  Then let's discuss how to better lay it out.  _Then_ we can talk about the code.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and explain why two tables are involved.